# ESP32 SPP Congestion after sniff mode

Tags: esp32, bluetooth, streaming

I'm trying to use an ESP32 to stream position data over SPP, but I keep running into congestion issues - even when I remove debug logs etc.

Essentially I get a mode change event..
ESP_BT_GAP_MODE_CHG_EVT: mode: 2
..and then the phone/ client stops receiving, followed by a SPP Write Congested error on the ESP32.

Why is the ESP32 trying to go into sniff mode? I've been searching articles and posts to figure out why the ESP32 does this in the first place, but I'm having trouble understanding. I'd really like to ensure the ESP32 focuses on streaming SPP data while it's connected.

How do I make the ESP32 stream continuously rather than going into sniff mode?

Comment: which post are you not understanding?  ... which part is unclear?

Comment: @jsotola reading this article, it seems sniff mode is a lower power state. What's not clear is why the ESP32 is doing this and how to convince it to stop https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Sniff-and-Sniff-Sub-rating-Modes_WP_V10.pdf